# Religious belief as a consequence of self-reliance

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, evolution

Self-reliance doesn't come naturally to many people, but one could argue that self-reliance is an important factor in both natural and sexual selection. Also many religious people achieve self-reliance because of the dogmas in their faith. Thus, one could say that religious belief is a consequence of evolution.

So, my question is whether there are any arguments for religious belief favoring self-reliance rather than God's existence.

Comment: I would argue that self-reliance is a factor in certain social systems, but not intrinsic, or even predominant, in nature. Examples of herd animals, hive animals, and social animals would all seem to demonstrate that lone self-reliance is in the minority in terms of traits that increase survival.

Comment: I would also ask, "Is a system of belief grounded on self-reliance be considered a religion?" Tony Robbins is a prominent self-help author, who has published books on self-reliance and inner strength; Unlimited Power, Unleash the Power Within and Awaken the Giant Within. These seem to fit the criteria on the perspective you are investigating, but I don't know if they would be classified as a religion (my intuition says they generally would not).

Comment: @alampert22 "Is a system of belief grounded on self-reliance be considered a religion?" that's a very good question, although it's a different one, what I'm asking is for any arguments in favor of religious beliefs being a sub-product of evolution selecting religious people that achieved self-reliance because of their faith.

Comment: "God helps those who help themselves"?

Comment: @JosephWeissman Exactly! ...and the word God could also be substituted by anything that helps achieve self-reliance.

Comment: @alampert22 Just for clarification, I could happen that at some point some system of beliefs grounded on self-reliance could have acquired some religious connotations, just like Scientology.